# E-mail entity is not sent unless the workflow is manually started

Tags: email, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I have a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 deployment that has workflows that send e-mails to users. The e-mails were being sent as normal before but they suddenly stopped working.

If I manually create an e-mail entity or trigger a workflow by hand the mails are sent as expected. However when they are automatically triggered the status of the e-mail is still marked as sent but they are not sent to user.

I tried restarting the e-mail router to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a background workflow is triggered, it will run as the owner of the workflow. When it is manually triggered, it will run as the user who manually triggered it.

Check to make sure the owner of the workflow has correct email router settings. You could also assign the workflow to yourself since you know your email settings are working.